# How to listen on an IPv6 address using cpprestsdk http_listener?

Tags: ipv6, cpprest-sdk

I passed an url `http://2001:420:589a:2009::101/`, which included an IPv6 address of my test server, to the constructor of http_listener and then called `http_listener.open().wait()`, unfortunately I got an exception saying `resolve: Service not found`.

I'm wondering how to listen on an IPv6 address correctly using cpprest http_listener. Or does http_listener not support IPv6 at all currently?

I'm using cpprestsdk v2.9.1.

Comment: You must enclose the IPv6 address in square brackets for a URL: `http://[2001:420:589a:2009::101]/`. This is covered in _[RFC 2732, Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for your reply.

I have tried `http://[2001:420:589a:2009::101]/` but got an exception from cpprest-sdk saying `provided uri is invalid: http://[2001:420:589a:2009::101]/`.

Seems web::uri in cpprest-sdk does not support ipv6 address with square brackets format yet.

Comment: To be more exact, I can successfully listen on an IPv4 address or an  domain name which would be resolved into an IPv6 address, however listening on an IPv6 address is always failed.